# Campo busca perde valor ao clicar em outra pagina

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma table referente a acessos de um determinado sistema. Nela eu tenho uma paginação com todos os acessos do sistema, quando eu pesquiso um determinado acesso no campo de pesquisar, a paginação se aplica aos campos mas na hora de clicar no link, volta como se fosse do inicio.
Pelo que eu percebi, o campo e a variavel perde o valor ao clicar na pagina, como eu poderia salvar o valor que eu coloquei no campo dentro do campo pesquisar ou em uma variavel?

Estou passando o link das paginas pela url. Coloquei o valor da variavel do cammpo pesquisar no canto esquerdo para exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

manual_sistema.php

```
            <div class="col s12 l12 paginacao" >
            <div class="col l5 s12 right">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 l12">
                        <input id="pesquisa" name="pesquisa" type="text">
                        <label for="pesquisa">Pesquisar Acesso...</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>



        </div>

        <div class="col l12 s11" id="acessosTable"><!-- DIV TABLE !-->

            <?php
                include_once 'pesquisaAcesso.php';
            ?>

        </div>

<script>
    $("#pesquisa").keyup(function(){
    var busca = $("#pesquisa").val();

    $.post('pesquisaAcesso.php', {busca: busca},function(data){
      $("#acessosTable").html(data);
    });


  });

</script>
```

pesquisaAcesso.php

```
include_once '../conecta_banco.php';


@define('QTDE_REGISTROS', 8); //define os acessos listados por pagina  
@define('RANGE_PAGINAS', 4); //define as paginas que ira mostrar de acordo com a atual.


$pagina_atual = (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) ?  $_GET['page'] : 1; //operador ternario || verifica se existe o numero da pag, caso nao, atribui a pagina 1 ao mesmo
$linha_inicial = ($pagina_atual -1) * QTDE_REGISTROS;  //calcula a linha inicial da consulta para mostrar a lista dos acessos

@$busca = $_POST['busca'];

$query = $conecta->prepare("SELECT * FROM acessos WHERE descricao LIKE '%$busca%'  LIMIT {$linha_inicial}, " . QTDE_REGISTROS);
$query->execute();
$fetchAll = $query->fetchAll();
$count= $query->rowCount();

//conta todos os registros que existem na tabela  
$sqlContador = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_registros FROM acessos where descricao LIKE '%$busca%' ";  
$stm = $conecta->prepare($sqlContador);  
$stm->execute();  
$valor = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);  

/* Idêntifica a primeira página */  
$primeira_pagina = 1;  

/* Cálcula qual será a última página */  
$ultima_pagina  = ceil($valor->total_registros / QTDE_REGISTROS);  

/* Cálcula qual será a página anterior em relação a página atual em exibição */  
$pagina_anterior = ($pagina_atual > 1) ? $pagina_atual -1 :  1;  

/* Cálcula qual será a pŕoxima página em relação a página atual em exibição */  
$proxima_pagina = ($pagina_atual < $ultima_pagina) ? $pagina_atual +1 :  1;  

/* Cálcula qual será a página inicial do nosso range */    
$range_inicial  = (($pagina_atual - RANGE_PAGINAS) >= 1) ? $pagina_atual - RANGE_PAGINAS : 1 ;  

/* Cálcula qual será a página final do nosso range */    
$range_final   = (($pagina_atual + RANGE_PAGINAS) <= $ultima_pagina ) ? $pagina_atual + RANGE_PAGINAS : $ultima_pagina ;  

/* Verifica se vai exibir o botão "Primeiro" e "Pŕoximo" */  
$exibir_botao_inicio = ($range_inicial < $pagina_atual) ? 'mostrar' : 'esconder';

/* Verifica se vai exibir o botão "Anterior" e "Último" */  
$exibir_botao_final = ($range_final > $pagina_atual) ? 'mostrar' : 'esconder';

if($count >0){

    echo $busca;
    echo '<ul class="pagination center" >';
    echo '<li class="waves-effect"><a href="manual_sistema.php?page='.$pagina_anterior.'"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>';
    echo '';

    for ($i=$range_inicial; $i <= $range_final; $i++){
        $marcador = ($i == $pagina_atual) ? 'active' : '' ;
        echo '<li class="waves-effect '.$marcador.' paginas"><a href="manual_sistema.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';  
    }

    echo '';
    echo '<li class="waves-effect"><a href="manual_sistema.php?page='.$proxima_pagina.'"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>';
    echo '</ul>';



    echo '<table class="highlight bordered">';
    echo '<head>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Acesso</th>';
    echo '<th>Permissão</th>';
    echo '<th>Descrição</th>';
    echo '<th>Sistema</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</head>';

    foreach($fetchAll as $acessoPesquisa){

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td style="user-select: none;"><b>'.$acessoPesquisa['nome_acesso'].'</b></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$acessoPesquisa['permissao'].'</td>';
        echo '<td style="user-select: none;">'.$acessoPesquisa['descricao'].'</td>';
        echo '<td style="user-select: none;">'.$acessoPesquisa['sistema'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

}else{
    echo '<br><div class="center">Nenhum acesso encontrado com os parâmetros pesquisados.</div>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

pastebin.com/p7wh9bPn

Comment: Coloque o código **sempre** aqui, pode até deixar em outro lugar e passar o link, mas tem que estar na pergunta **sempre** todo o código relevante

Comment: De preferência nunca colocar links externos, isso previne que um dia este link pare de funcionar e a pergunta se torne incompreensivel. @GuilhermeCostamilam

Comment: Corrigi o código

Comment: @Francisco, não tem problema deixar links externos (pelo contrário, ajuda bastante quando há um código rodando em algum lugar onde a pessoa pode tentar alguma solução de forma simples, já que aqui não é possível rodar linguagens como Python, Java, SQL, etc), desde que sempre tenha o código também aqui de forma completa

Comment: Eu já não tinha respondido sua pergunta ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toda vez que tu troca de página os dados do post são resetados por isso você perde o $_POST['busca'], então tu deve guardar isso em algum lugar, o lugar mais facíl é guardar na session, botando somente isso já deveria funcionar.

```
// pesquisaAcesso.php
// ...
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if (isset($_POST['busca'])) { 
    $_SESSION['busca'] = $_POST['busca'];
}

@$busca = $_SESSION['busca'];
// ...
```

Documentação da [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).
Uma pergunta igual a sua [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791414/storing-form-data-as-a-session-variable).

Comment: Deu certo cara! so tenho que adaptar agora ao meu código. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Teria como eu salvar o value do campo ao mudar de paginas com base no meu código ?

Answer (score 1):

Sessões resolvem o problema mas não são necessárias

No jQuery troque por

```
$.get('pesquisaAcesso.php?busca='+busca, function(data){ ... })
```

É mais semântico que faça uma requisição do tipo GET

No PHP, pegue a variável de pesquisa por GET em vez de POST e adicione essa variável aos links de navegação

```
@$busca = $_POST['busca'];

//...

echo $busca;
echo '<ul class="pagination center" >';
echo '<li class="waves-effect"><a href="manual_sistema.php?page='.$pagina_anterior.'&busca='. $busca.'"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>';
echo '';

for ($i=$range_inicial; $i <= $range_final; $i++){
    $marcador = ($i == $pagina_atual) ? 'active' : '' ;
    echo '<li class="waves-effect '.$marcador.' paginas"><a href="manual_sistema.php?page='.$i.'&busca='. $busca.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';  
}

echo '';
echo '<li class="waves-effect"><a href="manual_sistema.php?page='.$proxima_pagina.'&busca='. $busca.'"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>';
echo '</ul>';
```